# Expected CSS "Home" to Return Something RSpec issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, selector

I am trying to get my test suite working and am having some issues.

```
#home_controller_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'

describe HomeController do
  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "should be successful" do
      get 'index'
      response.should be_success
    end
    it "should have the right h2" do
      get 'index'
      response.should have_selector('h2', :content => 'Home')
    end
  end
end
```

The first test works and passes just fine.  Any time I try to run

```
response.should have_selector('[anything]')
```

it gives this error:

```
2) HomeController GET 'index' should have the right h2
   Failure/Error: response.should have_selector('h2','Home')
   expected css "Home" to return something
 # ./spec/controllers/home_controller_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I'm using Rails 3.1 and RSpec 2.6 and have already uninstalled and reinstalled Rspec. The same result happens in all of my controller tests.

Any ideas how to fix this error?

Thanks in advance!

Edit:
Uninstalled all gems.  Reinstalled all gems.  Re-setup RSpec, Capybara and Guard.  Seems to be working now.  Thanks for the help.  Not sure what was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default RSpec doesn't render templates in controller specs. You can either:

1) Move the test into a view spec

2) Add `render_views` to the describe block in the controller spec, which will then render the template.

Option 1 is preferred IMO. You could also use a request spec to test for content. If you are writing request specs, view specs are usually superfluous.

Comment: I had 'render_views' in previously and just tried it again with no change in behavior.  It seems that 'render_views' isn't doing its job.

Comment: Interesting update: have_content("[something]") works properly, but have_selector("[something]") does not.

Comment: Could you edit the question to show the spec that is failing?

Answer (score 2):

With rspec-rails gem V. 2.10.0 It worked good for me

```
it "should have the right title" do
  visit '/pages/howto'
  page.should have_selector("title", :text => "Abusa.me | Como funciona?")
end
```

Comment: This did it for me for some reason but I don't understand what is the difference between 'visit' and 'get'. 'visit' makes it work but 'get' doesn't. Why is that?